# No com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle registered with name: default

Tags: android, libgdx

i am new to libdgx..
I wanted to create a button with background image, I made images's pack with gdx-texturepacker.jar and then loaded it in TextureAtlus, but now whever i run my program it gives this error

No com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle registered with name: default

My code

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx; 
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Music;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas; 
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin;


public class Desperate implements ApplicationListener {

SpriteBatch batch;
int soundcheck=0;
Music music;
Actor background;
Actor red_player;

Button b;
TextureAtlas atlas;
Skin skin;

int x;
int y;

@Override
public void create() {  

    x = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth();
    y = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight();

    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/open.wav"));

    background = new Actor("data/green_surface.png",                                                                       

    Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth(),
Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight(),0,0);
    red_player = new Actor("data/red2.png", 100,150,230,120);
    atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("ui/button.pack"));
    skin = new Skin(atlas);
    b = new Button(skin);

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

    red_player.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {      


    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){


        red_player.position.x+=1f;

red_player.actor.setPosition(red_player.position.x,red_player.position.y);

    }



    batch.begin();
    //batch.draw(mario,0,0);
    background.actor.draw(batch);
    red_player.actor.draw(batch);
    b.draw(batch, 0);
    //front.draw(batch);

    batch.end();

    if(soundcheck==0)
    {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        //music.play();
        //sound.play(1f);
        soundcheck=1;
        System.out.println("Sound played!");
    }

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {


}

@Override
public void pause() {
}

@Override
public void resume() {
}
}
```

plzz tell me what should i do, or if i am not on a right path then tell me what is the easiest way to draw button on screen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
b = new Button(skin);
```

is the same as

```
b = new Button(skin,"default");
```

so its looking for a style definition from a .json **skin file**, which it seems you don't have

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: { up: btn_default_normal, down: btn_default_pressed, over: btn_default_focused, disabled: btn_default_disabled, font: default-font, fontColor: text-<col> , downFontColor: text-<col>, overFontColor: text-<col>, disabledFontColor: text-<col>},
```

It seems if you initialize your Skin without a **skinFile** argument like you did here...

```
 skin = new Skin(atlas);
```

...then you wont be able to pass the Skin as an argument to your scene2d.ui elements constructor.  Those constructors that have a Skin parameters assume you have this skinFile, and its just for the convenience to use the 'default' style or some other style on initialization.

If you have a Skin with only the TextureAtlas, you can still do stuff like this:

```
skin.getDrawable("mypackedimage");
```

Mostly though I assume its purpose is to build your Skin dynamically during runtime, instead of the persistant .json method of skinning.

You should google how to make your own Skin file, theres some **free** ones on LibGDX forums as well.

Answer (score 3):

Skins are useful if you're using lots of styles and different customized UI components. If you only need a few buttons you can use the straight forward aproach like this.

```
    TextureAtlas mAtlas;
    TextureRegionDrawable drawableUp = new TextureRegionDrawable( mAtlas.findRegion("up") );
    TextureRegionDrawable drawableDown = new TextureRegionDrawable( mAtlas.findRegion("down") );
    TextureRegionDrawable drawableChecked = new TextureRegionDrawable( mAtlas.findRegion("checked") );

    ButtonStyle btnStyle = new ButtonStyle(drawableUp, drawableDown, drawableChecked);
    Button t = new Button(btnStyle);
```